# How to Dynamically refresh / reload a KML layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, embeddable-web-maps

I have previously asked this question to no avail so I thought putting this up here would be a good idea.

**Here is an example on:**

How to Refresh / Reload a KML layer in OpenLayers. Dynamic KML Layer. See my answer below.

---

**TLDR:** See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Figured seen as it was hard enough for me to find information on this I would add this:

---

**1)**

Create the KML Layer:

```
            //Define your KML layer
            var MyKmlLayer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("This Is My KML Layer", {
                //Set your projection and strategies//
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                //set the protocol with a url//
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    //set the url to your variable//
                    url: mykmlurl,
                    //format this layer as KML//
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                        //maxDepth is how deep it will follow network links//
                        maxDepth: 1,
                        //extract styles from the KML Layer//
                        extractStyles: true,
                        //extract attributes from the KML Layer//
                        extractAttributes: true
                    })
                })
            });
```

**2)**

Set the URL for the KML Layer:

```
//note that I have host equal to location//   //Math.Random will stop caching//
var mykmlurl= 'http://' + host + '/KML?key=' + Math.random();
```

**3)**

Set the interval in which to refresh your layer:

```
           //function called// //timer// //layer to refresh//
window.setInterval(UpdateKmlLayer, 5000, MyKmlLayer);
```

**4)**

The function to update the layer:

```
            function UpdateKmlLayer(layer) {
                //setting loaded to false unloads the layer//
                layer.loaded = false;
                //setting visibility to true forces a reload of the layer//
                layer.setVisibility(true);
                //the refresh will force it to get the new KML data//
                layer.refresh({ force: true, params: { 'key': Math.random()} });
                //- <3 from Thqr -//
            }
```

---

Hopes this makes it easier for some others out there. Good luck.

Comment: What if your KML is local or on a networked drive?

Answer (score 2):

I have been putzing around with this to no avail.  Would someone mind taking a look at my code and telling me what I am doing wrong?  Thank you!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/api/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAl9RMqSzhPUXAfeBCXOussRTQDbvAygy0cfGJr8dEMAYKf3RWNBQqP9mjKIsqTfmAlz5LOJ3Xpy5s4w'></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map;

  function init() {
    // Create the map object
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    // Create a Google layer
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Streets", // the default
        {numZoomLevels: 20}
    );
    // Add layer to map
    map.addLayer(gmap);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-112.1161, 33.6636), 13);         
  }

  var MyKmlLayer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("This Is My KML Layer", {
            //Set your projection and strategies//
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            //set the protocol with a url//
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                //set the url to your variable//
                url: C:/Users/person/desktop/test.kml,
                //format this layer as KML//
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    //maxDepth is how deep it will follow network links//
                    maxDepth: 1,
                    //extract styles from the KML Layer//
                    extractStyles: true,
                    //extract attributes from the KML Layer//
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });

    var proposedanchorpositionurl = 'http://' + host + '/KML?key=' + Math.random();

    window.setInterval(UpdateKmlLayer, 5000, MyKmlLayer);

    function UpdateKmlLayer(layer) {
            //setting loaded to false unloads the layer//
            layer.loaded = false;
            //setting visibility to true forces a reload of the layer//
            layer.setVisibility(true);
            //the refresh will force it to get the new KML data//
            layer.refresh({ force: true, params: { 'key': Math.random()} });
            //- <3 from Thqr -//
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1 id="title">test</h1>
<div id="map" class=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So sorry, I had to correct your imperfect codes. Should run this time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the Refresh strategy. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Refresh-js.html

Answer (score 0):

untested but something like this?

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map;

  function init() {
    // Create the map object
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    // Create a Google layer
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Streets", // the default
        {numZoomLevels: 20}
    );
    // Add layer to map
    map.addLayer(gmap);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-112.1161, 33.6636), 13);         


  var KMLURL = 'C:/Users/person/desktop/test.kml?' + Math.random();

  var MyKmlLayer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("This Is My KML Layer", {
            //Set your projection and strategies//
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            //set the protocol with a url//
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                //set the url to your variable//
                url: KMLURL,
                //format this layer as KML//
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    //maxDepth is how deep it will follow network links//
                    maxDepth: 1,
                    //extract styles from the KML Layer//
                    extractStyles: true,
                    //extract attributes from the KML Layer//
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });

    window.setInterval(UpdateKmlLayer, 5000, MyKmlLayer);

    function UpdateKmlLayer(layer) {
            //setting loaded to false unloads the layer//
            layer.loaded = false;
            //setting visibility to true forces a reload of the layer//
            layer.setVisibility(true);
            //the refresh will force it to get the new KML data//
            layer.refresh({ force: true, params: { 'key': Math.random()} });
            //- <3 from Thqr -//
        }
 }
</script>
```